# sorting table data onto different sheets in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

trying to copy rows from the first sheet in my document onto different sheets using key word references. i am using the below code and even tho i have the same values in my log it wont sort.can some one please help

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rXlGPpTCZreDweJGCNil_OdCzeL9-uskw_DIRQsS0JU/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function sortAndSeperate() {
 var i = 3;
 var days = 11;
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var d =ss.getSheetByName("Coming Up work").getRange(2, days );
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Coming Up work");
 var worker = ss.getSheetByName("Reuben");
 var workerName =ss.getSheetByName('Setup').getSheetValues(1,1,1,6)
 Logger.log(workerName)
 var rangeMonday =sheet1.getSheetValues(i,11,1,6);
 Logger.log(rangeMonday)
 //var rangeTuesday=sheet1.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
 var worker = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reuben");
 var copyrange = worker.getRange(i - 1, 1, 1, 10); 
 
 

  
if (rangeMonday == workerName ) {
var paste =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Coming Up work").getRange(i,1,1,10).copyTo(copyrange)
var dateis = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Coming Up work").getRange(2 , days )
var paste2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reuben").getRange(i - 1,5)
var paste3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reuben").getRange(i - 1,6)
dateis.copyTo(paste2)
dateis.copyTo(paste3)
}
 else {
  Logger.log('It is finished.');
 }
  
}
}
}
```

Comment: Note that you are performing an equality test between two objects, the object `workerName`, and the object `rangeMonday`. This equality comparison does **not** compare their properties. I recommend reviewing a JavaScript reference and then rewriting your method, making sure to use comments to help describe the intent of each block of code. It may be very helpful to write all these comments **first**, describing the general flow of your function, and only then begin writing the actual code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice. shall do. fairly new to the hole coding thing as you can most likley tell by my code. thanks